# Pick contact from contact list android

Tags: android, sms, contacts

i am creating an sms app, in compose sms fragment I start the contact activity for result and `onResultActivity` get the result.
my code is working for those contacts which are saved in phone, but giving `nullPointerException` for those contacts which are fetched from facebook,
my code is this..

```
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
     pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
   startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 1001);
```

and in `onResultActivity`

```
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            setContactBubble(name);
            // Do something with the phone number...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Call this method in onActivityResult

```
public String getNumberContacts(Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber = "";
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            int hasPhone = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (hasPhone == 1) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    break;
                }
                phones.close();
            }
            break;
        }

        cursor.close();

        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Comment: i need both name and number, also from contacts which are fetched from facebook